# How to create cloudwatch alarm for multiple ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Did found the similar question earlier but no solution there.
How to create cloudwatch alarm for multiple ec2 instances?

Let's say I have 15 ec2 instances, I can group them with a tag, how to create single cloudwatch alarm for only these set of machines?

There are other solutions mentioned to create a script to create individual alarm for all these machines, but how to use a single alarm for all the instances?

Comment: Could you give more details as to what you need to accomplish. Which instance's metric are we talking about? the alarm will set off based on amount of instances or at least one?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following article, it's possible but non-trivial:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/use-tags-to-create-and-maintain-amazon-cloudwatch-alarms-for-amazon-ec2-instances-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

@user2331760   Were you able to find a solution for this? a global alarm instead of creating one for every EC2 instance? thanks